# Race condition while trying to update a map

Tags: go, rpc, race-condition, goroutine

### Introduction

I am trying to build a client-server application in /go.

There is only one instance for the server which contains list of tasks, which are nothing but string data. The server maintains a map of task and it's allocation status.

On the other hand the client can have multiple instances, and requests the server for the tasks. When a task is allocated the server updates allocation status to true.

The communication between the client and server is over go rpc.

Please refer to this [image: diagram] for better understanding.

To mimic multiple clients, I am spinning up multiple go routines in a single application that make request to the server.

### Code

#### Server

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/rpc"
    "sync"
)

type Container struct {
    mu   sync.Mutex
    list map[string]bool
}

var ListOfTasks Container

func (c *Container) UpdateList() string {
    var t string
    ListOfTasks.mu.Lock()
    defer ListOfTasks.mu.Unlock()
    for k, v := range c.list {
        if !v {
            c.list[k] = true
            fmt.Println("Task Name", k)
            return k
        }
    }
    return t
}

// RPC Code
type RPCServer struct{}

type Input struct {}

type Output struct {
    Message string
}

func (s *RPCServer) GetTask(i *Input, o *Output) error {
    o.Message = ListOfTasks.UpdateList()
    return nil
}
//

func init() {
    ListOfTasks = Container{}
    ListOfTasks.list = map[string]bool{
        "task1" : false,
        "task2" : false,
        "task3" : false,
    }
}

func main() {
    some := new(RPCServer)
    rpc.Register(some)
    rpc.HandleHTTP()

    fmt.Println("Listening on port 1234")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("bruh", err.Error())
    }
}
```

#### Client

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/rpc"
    "sync"
)

type Input struct {
    Name string
}

type Output struct {
    Message string  
}

func main() {
    client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", "localhost:1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("bruh!", err.Error())
    }

    arg := &Input{} 
    reply := Output{}

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(4)

    for i := 0; i< 4; i++ {
    go func(gori int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        err = client.Call("RPCServer.GetTask", arg, &reply)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("bruh!", err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf("#%d: message: %s\n", gori, reply.Message)
    }(i)    
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

### The Problem

When multiple clients make request to the server asking for a task, we run into a race condition, which is not detected by the golang's race detector. It can be observed in the application's output.

#### Server's output

```
Listening on port 1234
Task Name task1
Task Name task2
Task Name task3
```

#### Client's output

```
#1: message: task3
#2: message: task3
#0: message: task3
#3: message: task3
```

The server allocates different tasks to each worker but on the worker's end, everyone receives the same task.

I have lock over the entire for loop where we are searching for an unallocated task.

### Other things that I have tried (but didn't work)

1. Using `sync.Map`: Still ended up with a race condition, which was detected by the golang race detector.
2. Applying lock only on `c.list[k] = true`: Which caused the same issue that I am facing now.

---

I have my suspicion on the way I am applying the lock, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I know the problem is caused since there are multiple go routines trying to read from and update the map. And therefore I am applying the lock on the entire section where the reading and writing happens.

Most of the articles or StackOverflow posts that I read had both the server and client in the same application and avoided this problem by using channels. I am not sure how do I use channels in my use case.

Also, eventually this will become a map-reduce application, so I would have to store much more data other than a flag representing the allocation status.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The server is correct (although the code is a little muddled -- why use the mutex on the global `ListOfTasks` when you have a pointer receiver to your `Collection`?).

But the client code it wrong: you are using the same `&reply` pointer in all of your goroutines in the client, meaning that when one client goroutine receives a reply, all the goroutines see it, and then there's a race between receiving the reply and writing it.  You need to move the `reply := Output{}` into the goroutine.

I believe the race detector *will* detect this, but you have to run it on the client, not on the server.